# persistence in controller objects and UI updation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two questions on MVC controller for ASP

I have an ASP MVC controller like this

```
    public class DataToleranceController : Controller
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;
        private readonly IDataTolerances _dataTolerances;
        private IEnumerable<DataTolerance> dataTolerance = null;

        public DataToleranceController(DataContext context, IDataTolerances dataTolerances)
        {
            _context = context;
            _dataTolerances = dataTolerances;
            dataTolerance = _dataTolerances.GetDataTolerances();

        }

        public IActionResult DataPlus()
        {
            try
            {
                DataTolerance a = dataTolerance.First();
                a.FirstParam += a.FirstParamStep;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return Redirect("DataSettings");
        }
```

My first question :
The DataPlus() action gets called by a button click. But when I click the button I find dataTolerance object null. If I declare dataTolerance as static, then it obviously has the correct object reference and this function runs ok.

I would like to know if this is expected behavior ? And instead of using static to declare dataTolerance is there a correct way of doing this i.e. to also have persistence of dataTolerance object?

My second question :
The dataTolerance object's FirstParam member is displayed in my View. Like this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().FirstParam)
```

And I have a button on my UI like this

```
<input type="button" value="Step up" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DataPlus", "DataTolerance")'" />
```

Obviously, when I click the button

I would like the DataPlus() function called (and it calls the function fine) and then the new value should be updated back to the UI. How could I achieve this?

The Redirect method doesn't work in my case.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: A controller is used to parse a request or response.  You cannot call the controller directly is usually automatically triggered when data is received.  A controller is used at the server when a request is received and a controller is used by the client after a request is sent to the server to process the response.

Comment: Ok. But if my button action has to be listened to, then it has to be in the controller right? and in such case my controller needs to have this persistence isnt it ?

Comment: No.  The controller is normally an event that gets triggered when data is received.  The button would be used in a client to send the request and doesn't need to be inside the controller.

Comment: Ok. And to update the UI or just that portion of the UI alone should I do something differently and not Redirect ?

Comment: If you are updating it should be in the DataTolerance class.  Not the DataToleranceController class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should redirect to the action which return the current view. For example, the index is the current view:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public IActionResult DataPlus()
    {
        try
        {
            DataTolerance a = dataTolerance.First();
            a.FirstParam += a.FirstParamStep;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```